# Как вместо ползунка в QSlider сделать картинку?

Tags: c++, css, qt

Нужно сделать вместо ползунка картинку, которую можно будет двигать. Получается вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```css
 volume_slider->setStyleSheet(
                "QSlider::handle:horizontal {"
                "background : url(:/images/icon.png); width 30px;         height 30px"
                "}"    );
```

Нужно чтобы картинка была по центру и полностью была видна (размер картинки: 48x48). Можете подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: Замените background: на image: